# deleting DOI numbers in the references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, doi

I use TexStudio and created the references by using Mendeley. But the references includes DOI number at the end. I want to delete all DOI numbers or links.

What is the simplest method?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: DOIs can be very, very useful to identify an article quickly, I would only remove it if absolutely necessary. In the screenshot I can see no DOI, but if and how a DOI can be removed will depend on the bibliography style you use. If you want more concrete help with that you need to show us a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that reproduces the issue and tells us which style you use. If there are only a few DOIs a quick solution could be to delete the `doi` field in the `.bib` file.

Comment: I think `hypersetup` has a key `doi` that can be set to `false`. But, as said, an MWE would help in helping you.

Comment: It would be great, if you tell some more details. a MWE. which bst are you using?

Comment: Dear all thanks for your comments. @moewe, The references include DOI numbers or links at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `biblatex` if you do not want any online resource:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
            doi=false,
            url=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: ahh, right, it's not in `hypersetup`, but in `biblatex` options.

Comment: printing a DOI and linking a DOI are two different things.